# "cursor: pointer" just not working at all

Tags: html, css, angular

This is my angular template code:

```
   <!-- Modal -->
   <ng-template #levelsmodal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
         Select the levels you want to show in the table and chart
        </div>
        <div id="segments-modal" class="modal-body">
          <div class="row margin" *ngFor="let level of config?.data?.groups; let i = index" (click)="selectLevel(level)">
                <div  class="colorspan" [style.backgroundColor]="level.active ? colors[i] : 'gray'" class="colorspan">
                </div>
                <span class="level-labels pointer-cursor" [innerHTML]="getLabel(level)" ></span> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="c()">Close</button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
```

The class "pointer-cursor" is plain simple:

```
.pointer-cursor{
    cursor: pointer !important; 
    z-index: 500;
}
```

The z-index was only added for trying if it could make some difference, but it doesn't. I also tried applying this class to other parts like the wrapper div and so, but it's just not working. I keep seeing the normal "text cursor" instead of the pointer one...

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Please create a working demo. Code `cursor: pointer` is okay.

Comment: It may depend on the `innerHTML` that you insert inside of the `span`.  Applying the style attribute to all children of the span could work: `.pointer-cursor * { cursor: pointer; }`.

Comment: what do you output inside the span ? now we cannot test it because it's empty. If i put some text inside that span, the pointer works

Comment: Try inspecting the element to see if it has any overrides (or inner elements with cursor styling on them).  But as your question stands, it is impossible to answer as the code provided works fine, therefore I vote to close

Comment: The style could be overridden by a more specific selector. Try increasing the specificity, something like: `span.level-labels.pointer-cursor {cursor: pointer !important;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

```
::ng-deep .pointer-cursor{
   cursor: pointer !important; 
z-index: 500;
}
```

**Edit**
The `::ng-deep` combinator (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) ensures that the defined style applies to all child elements of the component, not only elements directly created by the component.

Since the element you want to style in inside a `ng-template` tag (so it does not belong directly to the component), you need to use this to style its elements

Comment: Wow, this worked! What does this ng-deep do? Thanks!